# .meta file clutter in Unity (using SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, unity-game-engine

Using SVN (Tortoise) in UNity3D clutters the script directory with .meta files. (one for every file)  It's gotten to the point that it really gets in my way as I go about my day.

Question: Is it safe/is there some way to hide/mask them?  I'm worried that just setting hidden attribute might cause a problem down the line (if it's safe, I consider that a fine answer!)

Note: Simply  sorting by type is not a solution here b/c of various cs and js file types mixed together in these directories) I'm joining a project already in development that was itself inherited from a different team, so yes, some oddities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .meta files are created for EACH and EVERY file and folder by design.

Unity3d Pro actually creates these along with every file.  Unity3d (non-pro) actually takes all the .meta files that are created in SVN and shoves them into a special format within a Temp/ directory.  You can't share this Temp/ directory on SVN since each person's machine will generate them differently.

However, if you were to upgrade your license to Pro, then the Pro version will take the files from your Temp/ directory and re-generate the .meta files as they are seen in SVN.

You must keep the .meta files.  For example, if you were to create an atlas (a SpriteCollection), but then delete this .meta file tied to it, all the files trying to use the atlas will break (on mine, everything turns to bright pink to show that the sprite Collection was corrupted).

Per [Unity](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html), you really want to keep the .meta files in your SVN whenever possible. On disk, it's okay if you hide them, but you must remember to delete the .meta file if you decide to get rid of the original file (delete MySprite.png, and you have to remember to delete MySprite.png.meta), which MAY be hard if you hide everything.

**EDIT:** The newer versions of Unity, 3.5.4~ish, now support .meta file generation for the non-pro versions. You can find this option under Edit->Project Settings->Editor (on a Mac, at least) and then switch "Version Control Mode" to "Meta Files".